# how can I count data from foreign key field in Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

models.py:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Properties(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Region = models.ForeignKey(Region, related_name='Region', on_delete=models.Cascade)
```

how can i count all properties which have the same region ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a filter query followed by a count. For example:

```py
london_properties_count = Properties.objects.filter(region__city='london').count()
```

Conventionally, you want to have fields on a model in lowercase, so instead of `Region = models.ForeignKey(..)`, have `region = models.ForeignKey(..)`